# Why do I have to tap button twice in my app?

Tags: swift, uibutton

I want to use buttons to change to different views but I have to tap the button twice in order to get it to act.

Any suggestions why I have to click twice?

Here is the code:

```
func tapEmergencyKitsDetected(sender:AnyObject) {
        myStack.push(thisNC)
        let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc : UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NCEmergencyKitsIntro") as! UIViewController
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func tapEmergencyPlanDetected(sender:AnyObject) {

    myStack.push(thisNC)
    let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc : UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NCEmergencyPlanList") as! UIViewController
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func tapEmergencyKits(sender: UIButton) {
    self.buttonEmergencyKits.addTarget(self, action: Selector("tapEmergencyKitsDetected:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
}

@IBAction func tapEmergencyPlan(sender: UIButton) {
    self.buttonEmergencyKits.addTarget(self, action: Selector("tapEmergencyPlanDetected:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button does respond to the first tap. It does exactly what you're telling it to do. But that thing is not something that has any *visible* result. When you say:

```
@IBAction func tapEmergencyKits(sender: UIButton) {
    self.buttonEmergencyKits.addTarget(
        self, action: Selector("tapEmergencyKitsDetected:"), 
        forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
}
```

all you're doing is reconfiguring what the button `self.buttonEmergencyKits` will do on its *next* tap. And then, indeed, on its next tap, it does it.

Comment: Another problem with that code is that you end up with a button that has multiple target-action pairs, since you are not removing the previous ones. You are heading for a very messy situation.

Comment: Thanks again. I noticed that when I corrected the first error and things are working properly now.

Answer (score 1):

try to remove connection between outlet or action for button from storyboard and recreate connection between outlet or function then clean and build your app again.